# Append the contents of latest Stackage nightly build to the global cabal config file

Tags: python, haskell

I've made the following python script to to append the contents of the latest Stackage nightly build to the global cabal config file (instead of going to the site, copying the page and appending it manually...). I would appreciate your feedback:

```
"""
Appends the latest stackage nightly sources from Stackage(http://www.stackage.org/nightly)
to your global cabal config file

It also makes two backups: one of the appended file and one of the unappended file

Stackage(http://www.stackage.org/) is a stable source of Haskell packages
"""

import requests
import shutil
from os.path import expanduser
from os.path import join

cabal_config_path = expanduser('~/.cabal/config')
stackage_nightly_url = 'https://www.stackage.org/nightly/cabal.config?global=true'

def write_cabal_config_backup(filename):
    """ 
    Writes a backup of the current global cabal config file in the ~/.cabal directory
    """
    shutil.copyfile(cabal_config_path, 
        join(expanduser('~/.cabal'), filename))

def unappend_stackage():
    """
    Unappend stackage sources from the global cabal config file. Be careful that 
    the sources must be at the end of the file, or this function will delete things 
    that you don't want it to.
    """
    def unappended_cabal_config():
        # Searches for the string 'Stackage' and returns a list made of the lines
        # of the file from there up, excluding the 'Stackage' line and everything below.
        with open(cabal_config_path) as f:
            cabal_config = f.readlines()
            for i in range(len(cabal_config)):
                if 'Stackage' in cabal_config[i]:
                    return cabal_config[:i]
        return cabal_config
    def write_unappended_cabal_config():
        cabal_config = unappended_cabal_config()
        with open(cabal_config_path, 'wt') as f:
            for line in cabal_config:
                f.write(line)
    write_unappended_cabal_config()

def append_stackage_nightly():
    """
    Appends stackage nightly sources to the global cabal config file
    """
    def get_stackage_nightly():
        r = requests.get(stackage_nightly_url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.text
    stackage_nightly = get_stackage_nightly()
    if stackage_nightly:
        with open(cabal_config_path, 'a') as f:
            f.write(stackage_nightly)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_cabal_config_backup('config_backup_appended')
    unappend_stackage()
    write_cabal_config_backup('config_backup_unappended')
    append_stackage_nightly()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unappend_cabal_config` can be more efficient and more elegant using a generator:

- Reading all the lines from the file when you may only need the ones until one containing "Stackage" is wasteful
- It's good to avoid the index variable in loops when possible

Like this:

```
def unappend_cabal_config():
    with open(cabal_config_path) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if 'Stackage' in line:
                return
            yield line
```

Answer (score 3):

You code doesn't follow all of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

- There are 8 lines that are too long.

  > Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.
  >
  > For flowing long blocks of text with fewer structural restrictions (docstrings or comments), the line length should be limited to 72 characters.
- Also you shouldn't have whitespace at the end of lines. 'def foo():  '.
- As others have said.

  > Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.
- You should avoid names such as `f` and `r`.
- CONSTANS should be fully capitalised.

Also there is [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) as well.

- Your docstrings should be in 'imperative mood'.
- You should have one line docstrings on one line not three.

---

Also why do you like nested scopes so much?

This just confused me at first, you return information, to then check the information, and then you use a 'function' on it.

```
def append_stackage_nightly():
    def get_stackage_nightly():
        r = requests.get(stackage_nightly_url)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return r.text
    stackage_nightly = get_stackage_nightly()
    if stackage_nightly:
        with open(cabal_config_path, 'a') as f:
            f.write(stackage_nightly)
```

You should `if stackage_nightly is not None:`, but you can just remove it.
And you are calling the functions 'the wrong way around'.
If you put the with statement in a function it would make more sense.
Here I will make it a generater, so that we minimise read/write operations.

```
def append_stackage_nightly():
    result = requests.get(stackage_nightly_url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        yield result.text
```

**Edit**: due to an error.

Now we can change the unappend_stackage so that it only writes to the file.
This is so we don't clear the file first. (The error)
We will make it take an iterable and write to the file.

```
def unappend_stackage():
    def unappended_cabal_config():
        with open(cabal_config_path) as f:
            cabal_config = f.readlines()
            for i in range(len(cabal_config)):
                if 'Stackage' in cabal_config[i]:
                    return cabal_config[:i]
        return cabal_config
    def write_unappended_cabal_config():
        cabal_config = unappended_cabal_config()
        with open(cabal_config_path, 'wt') as f:
            for line in cabal_config:
                f.write(line)
    write_unappended_cabal_config()
```

As we changed the `append_stackage_nightly`, we can loop through a generator.
Rather than making a new one.
And we will flatern out the function so it is a single function.

```
def unappend_stackage(iterable):
    with open(cabel_config_path, 'wa') as cabel_write:
        for line in iterable:
            if 'Stackage' in line:
                break
                # You may want this to be `continue`,
                # unless you know for sure there is no data after the first Stackage.
            cabel_write.write(line)
```

This removes the need to write to `cabel_config_path` twice, and read from it once.

Comment: Your `append_stackage_nightly` looks good. However, the `unappend_stackage` doesn't work as expected: instead of writing a file without the stackage sources, it writes an empty file. One more thing: using `f` after a `with open(file)` statement is common practice: see, for example, [Armin Ronacher's work](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/6e77cd709e16f7d1d654f67a5fc82e54bceae432/scripts/make-release.py).

Comment: Answering your question, the reason why I used inner functions in `unappend_stackage` was to make explicit my plan of getting the contents of an unappended file and then writing it. Perhaps I didn't do it in the best way, but thinking about and writing those two steps separately really sped up the making of the script. But I agree with you that in the case of `append_stackage_nightly` that was excessive.

Answer (score 2):

This code is really nicely written! I do have a few small nitpicky tips on style and such though, so here's a list of all the small things I see that can be improved.

1. Your two functions, `unappended_cabal_config`, and `write_unappended_cabal_config` could definitely use a docstring.
2. You should have two blank lines between top-level functions, not one.

Other than that, your code is really clean and nice looking! Good job!